# Adding prefix to WooCommerce order number based on user roles 2022

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, user-roles

I'm trying to prepend a prefix to an ID number based on user role using php. Would this work for just a single user role?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number');

function filter_woocommerce_order_number($order_number, $order) {
    // Get user
    $user = $order->get_user();
    
    // Roles
    $roles = (array) $user->roles;
    
    // Compare
    if (in_array('wholesale applicant', $roles)) {
        $prefix = 'WHLS';
    }
    
    return $prefix . $order_number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this works for me, but I used one of my own roles, which was train case ie: `wholesale_applicant`

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number');

function filter_woocommerce_order_number($order_number, $order)
{
    $roleToCheck = 'wholesale applicant';
    
    $user = $order->get_user();

    if ($user instanceof WP_User) {
        $rolesAndCaps = $user->get_role_caps();
        if (
            is_array($rolesAndCaps) &&
            array_key_exists($rolesAndCaps[$roleToCheck], $rolesAndCaps) &&
            true === $rolesAndCaps[$roleToCheck]
        ) {
            return 'WHLS' . $order_number;
        }
    }

    return $order_number;
}
```